# How do I hide the console window for my released MonoGame game?

Tags: xna, monogame

I am just finishing up my first game for the One Game A Month challenge which I wrote with the current MonoGame framework in Xamarin for Windows. I built the program in release mode, but running the executable produces **a console window besides the game window**. The console stays empty unless I deliberately cause an error to be logged, say by removing a required resource.

How can I get rid of this extraneous console window?

I looked through the project settings, but saw nothing alluding to removing the console window...

Comment: Nevermind. Found that changing the build settings to Executable with GUI from just Executable has solved the issue.

Comment: You should answer your own question then =)

Answer (score 2):

Found that changing the build settings to Executable with GUI solved this problem.

Answer (score 1):

Basically, change the configuration of Build "Console Application" to "Windows Application".

[image: Config sample]